# How to compare two dates and take one that is smaller? e.g MIN for DATE

Tags: excel, date

This question is for educational purposes only, as I have already solved this problem in a way I dislike...

Sheet looks following and has rows for months, in each row there is a column for days that month and for current month

[image]

I have a formula that calculates how many days have passed this month or month that has passed which is used in some later calculations.

```
=TODAY()-DATE(2017,6,1)+1
```

Currently at the end of month I have to go and change formula to (as they go over 31 day in a month)

```
=DATE(2017,5,31)-DATE(2017,5,1)+1
```

What I would like to do is something like:

`=MIN(TODAY(),DATE(2017,6,30))-DATE(2017,6,1)+1` to take whichever date is less, so I could do the formulas for the months in advance and not need to go back to it at the end of every month...

I can do it like `=MIN(TODAY()-DATE(2017,6,1),DATE(2017,6,30)-DATE(2017,6,1))+1` but it looks somewhat not nice...

**How do I compare two dates and take one that is smaller?**

Comment: @DanDonoghue Hi Dan, problem is when month lapses days go over 31 if `=TODAY()-DATE(2017,6,1)+1` used

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius why does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44621760/2627163) don't answer your question?

Comment: Because I am asking `How do I compare two dates and take one that is smaller?` I have working solution already: `=MIN(TODAY()-DATE(2017,6,1),DATE(2017,6,30)-DATE(2017,6,1))+1`

Comment: The answer to your specific question is `=MIN(date1, date2)`.  But you already know that.  So your question is not clear.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld `=MIN(Date(2017,1,1),Date(2017,5,1))` gives 42736 which isn't very usefull....

Comment: Why is that not useful?  That is how Excel stores dates.  `42736` is the value that Excel stores for `1-Jan-2017`.  If you format that as a date you will see that.  Excel stores dates as serial numbers with 1 = 1-Jan-1900

Comment: @RonRosenfeld It's not useful because `=MIN(Date(2017,1,1),Date(2017,1,2))` is also 42736.... But as someone with silver excel badge you already know that ;)

Comment: What would you expect the lowest date to be given the three dates you have posited?  `1-Jan-2017`, `2-Jan-2017`, `1-May-2017` ?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld `1-Jan-2017` and I would expect it to be in same format as it came into the MIN function... not in time from middle ages...

Comment: That's how Excel works.  All you need to do is format the cell to show a date.  You cannot control how Excel will format the result of a formula (unless you convert it to text)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld but hence the question, :) **How do I compare two dates and take one that is smaller?** Is there a way to convert the milisecond nonsenece into 'normal' date?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147062/discussion-between-ron-rosenfeld-and-matas-vaitkevicius).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a chat room discussion, it appears that one problem was the formatting of the results.

So `=MIN(TODAY(),DATE(2017,6,30))-DATE(2017,6,1)+1` is sufficient

Excel stores dates as serial numbers with `1 = 1-Jan-1900`.

If one wants to return a date, the cell containing the formula should be formatted as a date.

If one wants to return a numeric value, the cell containing the formula should be formatted as `General` or as a number with the appropriate number of decimals.

Excel does not always format the cell as desired by the user, so this may need to be edited.

Answer (score -1):

Days passed for that month is nothing but the day. You can directly use the below formula, I believe.

```
=min(day(date(2017,6,30)), day(DATE(2017,6,4)))
```

if you want that as a date. Then you can include another date function to include month and year. If you just want the smaller date itself, then you can directly use the date itself in the min function

```
=min(date(2017,6,30), date(2017,6,4))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer this wouldn't work as when month would lapse day would go to 1.... It has to compare Dates not days...

Comment: if you want to find the minimum date, you can directly use date itself., can you give the end result of what you wanted, It is not clear from your question, what should be the end result in all possible cases.

Comment: I know, but you can change the format of that cell as date, then you would get the date. Excel internally stores the date as numbers

Comment: But that would the require to add additional column for days.... `=MIN(TODAY()-DATE(2017,6,1),DATE(2017,6,30)-DATE(2017,6,1))+1` then would be a far better solution....

Comment: Yes, but you can still achieve it in one column by using =today() - min(date(2017,6,30), date(2017,6,4)) + 1

Comment: `=today() - min(date(2017,6,30), date(2017,6,4)) + 1` gives `15/01/1900` lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147016/discussion-between-karpak-and-matas-vaitkevicius).

Comment: If you want to find the lapsed days, it is number and now you need to change the format to Number.

Answer (score -2):

You have `TODAY()` function to get today date, you can get this month by `MONTH` function in excel.

`TODAY() - DATE(2017, MONTH(TODAY()), 1) + 1`

[reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MONTH-function-579a2881-199b-48b2-ab90-ddba0eba86e8)

Answer (score -2):

If you want to know how many days have passed, can't you just use

```
=TODAY()-(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1)
```

Comment: Without the +1 it will say 19 on the 19th, on the 19th you want to know that 18 days have passed hence the +1